# Highcharts issue with x-axis ticks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Having difficulty getting the correct tick marks on the x-axis with a Highchart. The y-axis is ticking correctly but the x-axis is not, even though both axes have the same data (I am plotting a parameter against itself using the same dataset). The datasets can change, so I am allowing the Highchart to determine the tick marks automatically, but the X and Y axis ought to be ticked the same since the data is the same, or so I would have thought.

Here are the settings:

```
var chartObject = {
            chart: {
                width:800,
                height: 600,
                alignTicks: true,
                marginRight: 200,
                zoomType: 'xy', 
            },
            title: {
                text: pName1 + ' vs '+ pName2
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    enabled: true,
                    text: pName1
                },
                min:0,
                max:16,
                ceiling: 16,
                minPadding:0,
                maxPadding:0
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: pName2
                },
                min:0,
                max:16,
                ceiling: 16,
                minPadding:0,
                maxPadding:0
            },
            legend: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Counts', 
                    style: {
                        fontStyle: 'italic'
                    }
                },
                symbolHeight: 12,
                symbolWidth: 12,
                align: "right",
                layout: 'vertical',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                squareSymbol: true,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                scatter: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 1,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true,
                                lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                        pointFormat: '{point.x} , {point.y} '
                    }
                }
            },
            series: ourSeries
        };
```

It is yielding the graph below, with mismatched x and y ticking:

[Click here to view graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyAAR.png)

I have read through the documentation and tried a variety of attributes to see if they might resolve the issue and they only yield other wrong variations on this theme.

Comment: Try to set the same tickInterval in both axes. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z46zw1L2/.

Comment: It seems that does work. I tried it previously but it appears I had the width/height set incorrectly (because I had not taken into account the margin) which was causing the problem. Thanks.